# Javascript sort stopping to work in the middle

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting a problem with that I think it's coming from the sort() method. When I call console.log("sorting alpha") or console.log("sorting alpha reverse") sometimes I get less calls then normal (e.g. I was getting 500 and suddenly I get 100). So the sorting doesn't happen properly.
I'm just subscribing to `links$` because I need it to be async.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    this.links$.subscribe((links) => {
      this.filteredLinks = this.filteredLinks.sort((a: Link, b: Link) => {
        if (this.activeFilters.alphabetical) {
          console.log("sorting alpha")
          return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (this.activeFilters.alphabeticalReverse) {
          console.log("sorting alpha reverse")
          return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
        } else if (this.activeFilters.ascendingDate) {
          const c: any = new Date(a.createdAt);
          const d: any = new Date(b.createdAt);
          return d - c;
        } else if (this.activeFilters.descendingDate) {
          const c: any = new Date(a.createdAt);
          const d: any = new Date(b.createdAt);
          return c - d;
        }
      });
      this.loadingSortAndFilter = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a semicolon missing after your two console.log statements...